# How to turn list of values into single items from valueMap step in cosmos db [Gremlin API]

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

In gremlin's tinkerpop [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#valuemap-step) i can turn list of values from valueMap into a single item by using the by() modulator.

But this doesnt work yet on azure cosmosdb (gremlin API)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you are trying to replace this command:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Test").valueMap().by(unfold())
```

I don't know cosmosDB and maybe there is a better way

but I think this query (if supported) will be equivalent:

```
g.V().hasLabel("company").local(
    __.valueMap(false).unfold()
       .group()
       .by(__.select(keys))
       .by(__.select(values).unfold()))
```

Comment: hello, i tried your answer with this command: `g.V().hasLabel('company').local(valueMap().unfold().group().by(select(keys))        .by(select(values).unfold()))`

and im getting an error with: `compositeObjField != null`

Comment: again I don't know cosmos, but maybe try to be more explicit query, I updated my answer